# query pandas cols with loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

i have the following df:

```
    country  sport  score
0   ita      swim   15 
1   fr       run    25
2   ger      golf   37
3   ita      run    17
4   fr       golf   58
5   fr       run    35
```

i am interested in some elements of categories only:

```
ctr = ['ita','fr']
sprt= ['run','golf']
```

i was hoping in something like this to extract them:

```
df[(df['country']== x for x in ctr)&(df['sport']== x for x in sprt)]
```

but while it doesn't throw any error it returns empty..

any suggestion?
i also tried:

```
df[(df['country']== {x for x in ctr})&(df['sport']== {x for x in sprt})]
```

EDIT:

the reason why want to use a loop, is cos i am actually interested in the 3 top scores of each combination, which i hoped to concat:

```
df1 = pd.concat(df[(df['country']== x for x in ctr)&(df['sport']== x for x in sprt)].sort_values(by=['score'],ascending=False).head(3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership:

```
df1 = df[(df['country'].isin(ctr))&(df['sport'].isin(sprt))]
print (df1)
  country sport  score
1      fr   run     25
3     ita   run     17
4      fr  golf     58
5      fr   run     35

df2 = df1.sort_values('score', ascending=False).groupby(['country','sport']).head(3)
print (df2)
  country sport  score
4      fr  golf     58
5      fr   run     35
1      fr   run     25
3     ita   run     17
```

Comment: hi jezrael, yes, sorry, see my edit.. i am interested in the 3 top for each combination, so i hoped to sort, head() and concat..

Comment: @lorenzo - Can you add more data to sample and add expected output?

Comment: see my edit, is it clearer? what i am interested is the top 3 of each combination, not just the top 3 absolute

Comment: as usual, jezrael, you are right. thank you so much! in this case, why head() is showing the head of each instead of the top 3 head of the grouped df?

Comment: @lorenzo - Do you need check by pairs? What is expected output from your sample data? Because `isin` test like `OR` - ita or fr and run or golf

Comment: this perfectly does the job, i don't want pairs, but combinations as you do. i am just wondering about the usage of head(), nevermid. thank you so much

Comment: @lorenzo - sure, it is top3 values per groups - so here are top1 for `fr  golf` (top2,3) missing, then top2 for `fr   run` - top3 missing and similar for third group `ita   run` top2,3 missing